Exception when using agracio/edge-js in vscode-extension
Created an ts-extension with "yo code".
Then I included edge-js and added some dummy usage to ensure that it got not optimized.
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as edge from 'edge-js';

if (edge === null) {console.log('no edge');};

...

When I start the extension and called the command I get the following error:
Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.ts-test' failed: Module did not self-register: '\\?\d:\data\develop\js\Reni.VSCode\ts-test\node_modules\edge-js\lib\native\win32\x64\20\edge_nativeclr.node'..

My system: 
Version: 1.92.2 (user setup)
Commit: fee1edb8d6d72a0ddff41e5f71a671c23ed924b9
Date: 2024-08-14T17:29:30.058Z
Electron: 30.1.2
ElectronBuildId: 9870757
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.14.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045



package.json
tsconfig.json
extension.ts
